# Add a backBarButtonItem to navigationItem without UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController, and I add a navigationItem to view header in InterfaceBuilder, I found I can't drag a backBarButtonItem to navigationItem, only leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem can be added. So I try to add backBarButtonItem to navigationItem element in my controller code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
   self.myNavigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
  [_backButton release];
}
```

But there is still no backBarButtonItem on view? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually set the leftBarButtonItem, not the backBarButtonItem, and only then after you set self.hidesBackBarButtonItem like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButtonItem = YES;
     self.myNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _backButton;
    [_backButton release];
}
```